# mitmdump not working with pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python.And i was trying to use mitmdump to crawl an app and use mongodb to store datus. But...I found no answer on google, and i got no idea what to do... my Windows10 platform.  I assume whether windows doesnt support it

> D:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python>mitmdump -s ScriptsTest.py
>   Loading script ScriptsTest.py
>   Addon error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-
>   packages\mitmproxy\addonmanager.py", line 42, in safecall
>       yield
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-
>   packages\mitmproxy\addons\script.py", line 102, in loadscript
>       ctx.master.addons.register(ns)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-
>   packages\mitmproxy\addonmanager.py", line 161, in register
>       self.master.commands.collect_commands(a)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-
>   packages\mitmproxy\command.py", line 144, in collect_commands
>       self.add(o.command_path, o)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-
>   packages\mitmproxy\command.py", line 151, in add
>       self.commands[path] = Command(self, path, func)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-
>   packages\mitmproxy\command.py", line 51, in **init**
>       sig = inspect.signature(self.func)
>     File "d:\users\administrator\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 3033, in signature
>       return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
>     File "d:\users\administrator\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 2783, in 
>   from_callable
>       follow_wrapper_chains=follow_wrapped)
>     File "d:\users\administrator\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 2183, in 
>   _signature_from_callable
>       raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
>   TypeError: MongoClient(host=['127.0.0.1:27017'], document_class=dict, 
>   tz_aware=False, connect=True) is not a callable object

here is my script code

```
import json
import pymongo
from mitmproxy import ctx

client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='127.0.0.1') 
db = client['igetget']
collection = db['books']


def response(flow):
    global collection
    url = 'https://dedao.igetget.com/v3/discover/bookList'
    if flow.request.url.startswith(url):
        text = flow.response.text
        data = json.loads(text)
        books = data.get('c').get('list')
        for book in books:
            data = {
                'title': book.get('operating_title'),
                'cover': book.get('cover'),
                'summary': book.get('other_share_summary'),
                'price': book.get('price')
            }
            ctx.log.info(str(data))
            collection.insert(data)
```